# Matching sets of tags in PHP with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-match, newline

I am currently working on protecting my AJAX Chat against exploits by checking all text in PHP before it is passed to the client. So far I have been successful with my mission except for one part where I require to match sets of image tags.

Overall I wish to have it pick up any instance of there being a newline character between a set tags which I have sort of managed, but the solution I have is greedy and matches newline characters outside of tags as well if there are multiple sets of tags.

At the moment I have the following which works if I wanted to match just `[img]{newline}[/img]`

```
if(preg_match('/\[\bimg\].*\x0A.*\[\/\bimg\]/', $text)){ //code }
```

But if I wanted to do `[img]image.jpg[/img]{newline}[img]image.jpg[/img]`, it only sees the very first and end tags which I do not want.

So now I ask, how do you make it match each set of tags properly?

Edit: For clarification. Any newline characters inside tags are bad, so I want to detect them. Any newline characters outside tags are good and I want to ignore them. The reason being, if the client processes a newline character inside of a tag, it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it ungreedy by putting `?` after the two `.*`

But note that your current solution will not match this:

```
[img]
look, two newlines!
[/img]
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but you can make `.` match newlines by adding the `s` modifier to your regex. Then it's just `"(\[img\](.*?)\[/img\])is"` to match it, and you can even capture that group and individually check it for newlines if you want.

Comment: I had already tried placing ? after .* before and it still matched wrongly. I believe you read my question wrong, so I added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the s modifier, like this:

```
if (preg_match('/\[\bimg\].*\x0A.*\[\/\bimg\]/s', $text)) { code }
```

See also the [PHP Documentation for Regex modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.